# Get the port from a python requests response

Tags: python-requests, port

I'm using the [magical python requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/).

I need to find out which port the request used to connect to the server.

I checked the W3 school doc : [Python requests.Response Object](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/ref_requests_response.asp)
But there isn't any object that fetch my need.

I am pretty sure it's a doable as the request find automatically the right port.
I should be able to get the port in the response right?

Why do I need the port?
Sometimes web server respond on non-standard port such as 8080 or so.
And I'm referencing url with their ports.

This code is not working for website that are not using standard port

```
url = 'https://google.fr'

resp = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=2)

print(resp.text)
```

This is what I am currently using:

```
    adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=1)
    resp_res = {'lines': 0, 'resp_code': 0, 'port': 'N/A', 'history': [], 'final_url': ''}
    session = requests.Session()
    url01 = 'https://google.fr'

    # Prepares a special HTTP request with a specific adapter
    session.mount(url01, adapter)

    # Send an hTTPS request
    try:
        resp = session.get(url01, verify=False, timeout=2)
        # Readible result
        resp_soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"html.parser")
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError, requests.Timeout,
            requests.TooManyRedirects) as e: # HTMLParser.HTMLParseError
        logging.error('scrap_website - HTTPS connection failed')
        logging.error(e)
    else:
        resp_res['lines'] = len(str.splitlines(str(resp_soup.prettify())))
        resp_res['resp_code'] = resp.status_code
        resp_res['port'] = 'HTTPS'
        resp_res['history'] = resp.history
        resp_res['final_url'] = resp.url
```

See for 'resp_res['port']', I need to find out which port the server is listening on.

Any ideas?

Steackfrite

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was missing the basis.

When you perform an HTTP request, requests will try to connect on port 80.

For HTTPS, requests will try to connect on port 443.

If you want an exotic port such as 8080 this is how you should do it :

```
resp = requests.get(http://example.com:8080)
```

And if you would like to try several ports, you have to do a loop.